# XCode 12.0.1 doesn't work for iPhone SE testing

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

This is as simple as it gets. I develop a simple UI interface without functionalities and such, and when I deploy on my iPhone SE 1 device, which is an actual physical device, it just gets a blank white screen, why is this bug happening? Regarding the app, it has only some basic elements, such as label and a button which does nothing. How can I see the actual elements on the screen. When I look it in the XCode, various devices, they appear to be working, i.e. they are displayed. Also, if I close the app, and re-run it from my iPhone by tapping on it, then the UI shows. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Rob Yes, the physical device.

Comment: And yes, I only want to test on my physical device. Not on simulator. I want it to work on my physical device. On my actual iPhone SE1 physical phone.

Comment: Why did my comment about you disappear?

Comment: Do you actually have the permission to delete my comments, on my own post? And I can't even delete yours?

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem a while ago, but it was for my iPhone 7 plus. The blank white screen was the launch screen. Turns out what happened was that I had an older version of Xcode Beta (version 12A6159), and when I downloaded the GM seed (version 12A7209), something was conflicting. Not sure what, but when I moved version 12A6159 to the trash and re-installed version 12A7209, it worked. This was back when Apple had just released iOS 14 back at the September event.

Comment: FWIW, in Xcode preferences, under [“Locations”](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/deva52afe8a4) there is a drop down for command line tools which often can be used to disambiguate Xcode versions.